# Error during upgrade on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

When I try to upgrade the software on my computer with `sudo apt-get upgrade` the following error occurs

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpam-systemd libsystemd0 libudev1 systemd systemd-sysv udev
6 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 5,051 kB of archives.
After this operation, 62.5 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 systemd-sysv amd64 229-4ubuntu11
  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.200 80]
Err:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libpam-systemd amd64 229-4ubuntu11
  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.200 80]
Err:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libsystemd0 amd64 229-4ubuntu11
  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.200 80]
Err:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 systemd amd64 229-4ubuntu11
  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.200 80]
Err:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 udev amd64 229-4ubuntu11
  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.200 80]
Err:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libudev1 amd64 229-4ubuntu11
  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.200 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd-sysv_229-4ubuntu11_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.200 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libpam-systemd_229-4ubuntu11_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.200 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libsystemd0_229-4ubuntu11_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.200 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd_229-4ubuntu11_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.200 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/udev_229-4ubuntu11_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.200 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libudev1_229-4ubuntu11_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 141.76.1.200 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

My `sources.list` looks like

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805)]/ trusty main restricted    
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted    

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted    

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe    

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse    

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse    

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse    

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner    

# deb http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/ # disabled on upgrade to xenial
# deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/ # disabled on upgrade to xenial    

deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org xenial main
deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org xenial main
deb [arch=armhf] http://linux-packages.resilio.com/resilio-sync/deb 
resilio-sync non-free
```

I tried to run the two recommended solutions but they do also not solve the problem. I tried to search for the problem but I was not able to find something similar.

Comment: Can you post your /etc/apt/sources.list ?

Comment: Very probably the package files have not been synchronised to your mirror yet (transferring files takes sonme time!). Try again in an hour.

Comment: I think the time does not affect the problem. I tried a week ago for the first time and still have the above described problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I guess your package manager list of packages and cache is obsolete.

**but why?**

You are using `xenial`, one of the packages that you are trying to reach is `libpam-systemd`, which your pkg manager tries to fetch from here:

```
http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libpam-systemd_229-4ubuntu11_amd64.deb
```

Which server responds you with a 404, that means it's does not exist.

If you check the [main repository](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libpam-systemd_229-4ubuntu11_amd64.deb), you will see that it's not there too.

And if you search for `libpam-systemd` in `xenial-updates` section at [Ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com). the result would be [229-4ubuntu16](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpam-systemd&searchon=names&suite=xenial-updates&section=all) while you are trying to reach 229-4ubuntu11, and the other thing is that this new version is available on your chosen repository. [here](http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libpam-systemd_229-4ubuntu16_amd64.deb) it is.

**What to do?**

Update your lists:

```
sudo apt update
```

It should do the work for you.

However, if after updating the lists, you still got the problem, try removing these files and then run the above command again:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin
```

Comment: This looks like it solved error. I'm not completely sure, but `sudo apt upgrade` shows nothing to do now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @SoS You're welcome, glad that it was helpful to you ;)

Comment: In my case this happened when launching a fresh, empty Ubuntu 16.04 image on Amazon AWS. Seems like `sudo apt update` must be run to bring it up to date.